# Django celery task_id is null

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to implement a progress bar in Django, I'm taking references from this code snippet I found http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2898/ but my efforts are in vane because I don't know what happening but the `task_id`for celery is always null when executes the method task, that's my code:

```
def add_categoria(request):
        if request.POST:
            form_cat = CategoriaModelForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
            if form_cat.is_valid():
                file = request.FILES['imagen']
                job = upload_image_categoria(request).delay()
                request.session['task_id'] = job.id
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'task_id':job.id}))
            else:
                return HttpResponseBadRequest(json.dumps(form_cat.errors),
                                            mimetype="application/json")
        else:
             form = CategoriaModelForm()
             return render_to_response("ventas/form.html",{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))


@task()
def upload_image_categoria(request):
        form = CategoriaModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        path = MEDIA_ROOT+'/categorias/%s' % form.cleaned_data['imagen'].name
        file = request.FILES['imagen']
        destination = open(path, 'wb+')
        porcentaje = 0
        acum = 0
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            time.sleep(0.1)
            current_task.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'current': porcentaje})
            acum += len(chunk)
            porcentaje = int((acum*100)/file.size)
            destination.write(chunk)

@csrf_exempt
def upload_state(request):
       """ A view to report the progress to the user """
       data = 'Fail'
       if request.is_ajax():
           if 'task_id' in request.POST.keys() and request.POST['task_id']:
               task_id = request.POST['task_id']
               task = AsyncResult(task_id)
               data = task.result or task.state
           else:
               data = 'No task id'
       else:
           data = 'This is not an ajax request'
       json_data = json.dumps(data)
       return HttpResponse(json_data, mimetype='application/json')
```

So, when I report the state of progress bar in `upload_image_categoria` at `current_task.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'current': porcentaje})` always I get this Traceback:

```
Traceback:
    File "/Users/Tone/blog-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/Users/Tone/blog-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/Tone/Documents/Proyectos/dgp/ventas/forms.py" in add_categoria
      446.             job = upload_image_categoria(request).delay()
    File "/Users/Tone/blog-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py" in __call__
      330.             return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/Tone/Documents/Proyectos/dgp/ventas/forms.py" in upload_image_categoria
      462.         current_task.update_state(state='PROGRESS',meta={'current': i, 'total': 100})
    File "/Users/Tone/blog-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py" in update_state
      695.         self.backend.store_result(task_id, meta, state)
    File "/Users/Tone/blog-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py" in store_result
      282.         self._store_result(task_id, result, status, traceback, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/Tone/blog-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py" in _store_result
      128.                             routing_key=task_id.replace('-', ''),

    Exception Type: AttributeError at /ventas/categorias/add/
    Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

That's my settings.py for celery options:

```
    BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest@localhost:5672//"
    CELERY_IMPORTS = ("ventas.forms",)
    CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
    CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = "mysql://root@localhost/dgp"
```

So I don't know what's happening, worker is correctly, settings (I guess, is correctly) and always I get the same, I prove in some other projects with the same settings (this project particularly http://iambusychangingtheworld.blogspot.com.es/2013/07/django-celery-display-progress-bar-of.html) and it works perfectly so I don't know why here not, something I'm missing? Any ideas would be appreciate.

Regards!

Comment: Any progress on this issue? I'm having roughly the same situation.